# Invalid firewall

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I have updated my symfony from 3.3 to 3.4 and now I'm getting an error after the update :

> Invalid firewall "main": user provider "main" not found.

This is coming from SecurityExtension.php.

I have no idea from where this can come from. 
My question is : Did anyone had this and solved it or has an idea about how to do it ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: SOLVED : I just had to rename my user provider to main...

Answer (score 1):

> I have no idea from where this can come from

The word "main" comes from security.yml, it could be that the firewall main doesn't exist or you renamed it.

[Link to docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html)

Comment: Well that's the point. The firewall main is still present in my security.yml